# Jquery Pulsate Times

Tags: jquery, effects

I use the function Pulsate (http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Pulsate). With the argument 'times' I can set the times the element pulsates. The Default value is 5, but how can I set it that the element will pulsate infinitely.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I recommend you don't use JQueryUI at all for this - it's a very simple animation and can be easily done without loading UI:

```
// DOM ready
$(function(){
    // Self-executing recursive animation
    (function pulse(){
        $('#my_div').delay(200).fadeOut('slow').delay(50).fadeIn('slow',pulse);
    })();
});
```

**Working demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/bSWMC/

As you can see, it can be tweaked quite easily by changing the speed of the fades and the duration of the delays.

The original JQueryUI `pulsate()` function uses a `for` loop for `times` so you can't achieve your result using this plugin without changing the logic of the plugin:

```
$.effects.pulsate = function(o) {
    return this.queue(function() {
        var elem = $(this),
            mode = $.effects.setMode(elem, o.options.mode || 'show');
            times = ((o.options.times || 5) * 2) - 1;
            duration = o.duration ? o.duration / 2 : $.fx.speeds._default / 2,
            isVisible = elem.is(':visible'),
            animateTo = 0;

        if (!isVisible) {
            elem.css('opacity', 0).show();
            animateTo = 1;
        }

        if ((mode == 'hide' && isVisible) || (mode == 'show' && !isVisible)) {
            times--;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < times; i++) {
            elem.animate({ opacity: animateTo }, duration, o.options.easing);
            animateTo = (animateTo + 1) % 2;
        }

        elem.animate({ opacity: animateTo }, duration, o.options.easing, function() {
            if (animateTo == 0) {
                elem.hide();
            }
            (o.callback && o.callback.apply(this, arguments));
        });

        elem
            .queue('fx', function() { elem.dequeue(); })
            .dequeue();
    });
};
```

Comment: Wow, thank you. Last question, if I use the fade-in,fade-out example the element disappears for some miliseconds, but all the elements under the fading element go up and down. Sorry for my English;-), so is it possible that the element fade in and out without disappearing?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your comment - Simply put the element in a wrapper with fixed dimensions :) http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/bSWMC/3/

Comment: No problem, stupid I dont saw it, but it works;-) Thank you very much!

Comment: Is there any way to stop this pulse effect? I'm checking a value via ajax and I want to stop this pulse effect when the values reaches 0. thanks

Comment: Sure you'd just replace `pulse` in `fadeIn('slow',pulse)` with a callback function that has a condition to check for your value and execute `pulse()` accordingly.

Comment: A couple problems:
1.  It actually makes the element disappear and any adjoining elements will flicker/jump as they move into the vacuum.
2.  No easy way to stop it.  I'd put the pulse() function in a setInterval() call, then you can store the timer and turn it off as needed.

Comment: Sure there is, put it in a DOM wrapper with a defined space;

Answer (score 12):

Jordy, you can use put the pulsate inside a function to accomplish the above.

```
//the function
function pulsateforever(){
$("element").effect("pulsate", { times:1 }, pulsatetime,function(){
//repeat after pulsating
pulsateforever();
});
}
//call function when DOM is ready
$(function(){
pulsateforever();
});
```

Make sure you replace ***element*** with the element you want to pulsate, and ***pulsatetime*** with the speed in which you want it to pulsate.

Comment: +1 This will absolutely work, though as I mentioned this shouldn't be using JQueryUI - a simple `$('element').fadeOut('slow').delay(500).fadeIn('slow',recursion..)` would be optimal I believe.

Comment: Ok, so what should I do? Dont use the UI Pulsate but Fade in and out? Thanks for help;-)!

Answer (score 3):

Based off of AlienWebguy's answer, but without "hide" and "show"ing the element, instead just animating the opacity:

```
(function pulse(){
            $( "#elem" ).delay(200).animate({'opacity':1}).delay(500).animate({'opacity':0},pulse);
        })();
```

Comment: this is quite nice and simple and does the job

Answer (score 1):

Check out this new [plugin](http://kilianvalkhof.com/jquerypulsate/)

Works like charm and the pulsate effect works on all browsers .

Answer (score -3):

Just a wild guess, but I'd try 0 or -1. If this doesn't help, you may just add a value that is close to unlimited, maybe 1000000 or something.